# Shortcut for line continuation (escaped newline) action

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

Does exist the way, binding line continuation action to specific key in the bash?

That is, instead pressing two keys `\` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, one after another, press two keys simultaneously, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Instead this:**
`$ echo one \`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
`> two \`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Do this:**
`$ echo one`, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = get backslash and newline
`> two`<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> - get backslash and newline, etc.

I have looked at readline binding and doesn't find such action.Would not say, that this functionality needed me so much :), just interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer in the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/readline#Macros) - it can be done by macros:

`bind '"\e\C-m":" \\\C-j"'`

It bind the needed functionality to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> combination.

Then it needed to add this line to the `.bashrc` file and this binding will work after reboot.

To look at your available macros, run `bind -s`:

```
$ bind -s
$ "\e\C-m": " \\\C-j"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that using bind command

```
bind '"\e[24~":"\\\n"'
```

I use `F12` because i don't know how to bind C-^M  i think its impossible bcos enter is C-M but you can use:

```
bind '"\C-m":"\\\n"'
```

Comment: Thanks, though I found the same solution itself 10 minutes ago, your answer  pointed me that binding to `C-m` broke `Enter` key :) But I added `Alt` key to my combination and now, it work how I was wanted. Either `Alt + Enter` or `Ctrl + Alt + m` doing the line continuation.